# If alpha is 0, RBG is 0 even with premultipyAlpha to false

Tags: three.js, shader, textures

I have a 3D model with a RGBA texture where the alpha value should be ignored (I must use those alpha values differently for some reflections effects).

[PNG specs say : colors are not premultiplied by alpha.](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Rationale.html)

Then, in shaders we should be able to ignore alpha values and only displaying RGB colors.

I tried many things, disabling `premultipliedAlpha` in `WebGLRenderer`, `Texture` and `Material` but RGB values are 0 if alpha is 0.

[image: Illustration of models with different textures]

In the example below, the models should have skin colored hands and neck but appear white.
On the center texture is loaded natively by the `FBXLoader`.
On the right texture is loaded by the `TextureLoader`.
On the left another texture without alpha is loaded by the `TextureLoader` for demonstration purpose.

For `ShaderMaterials`, the fragment shader is :

```c
void main() {
   FragColor = vec4(texture2D(map, vUv).rgb, 1.);
}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/premultiply-issue-weximh?file=/src/main.ts:2661-2912)

What I am doing wrong ? Is that a WebGL or THREE limitation ?

PS: using 2 textures is **not** an option

Comment: What's the demo supposed to look like? For me, left and right are identical. Center is overall darker. All skin seems skin coloured, with the center having a darker tone.

Comment: Thanks for comment. What device are you using and which browser ? It look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgieP.jpg on macOS & Windows on Chrome & Firefox

Comment: You may try to refresh your browser, I tried on Safari on iOS and all models had skin colored texture. But refreshing the page makes white hands appear all the time.

Comment: Right, yeah on my device the right model looks exactly like the left one. No white hands like in your picture. I use Chrome on Windows with a dedicated nvidia card.

Comment: Testing a bit further, it seems like it depends on GPU. When I run chrome or firefox using my integrated AMD GPU, then I do see your white hands. Unfortunately I don't know what could be causing this inconsistency, but I recommend you try to isolate the problem to a simple example that still reproduces the inconsistency.

Comment: Interesting... On the same device and the same browser, I can have two different results : working - https://jsfiddle.net/Sufhal/xjrcnt60/5/ & not working - https://rfr4hv.csb.app/ (both share the same code & same THREE revision 149)

Comment: Ok I found that its not GPU related but web servers are compressing/premultiplying png's when they cache the content so the content-length is lower than the 1st loading. It looks like this is the reason why the first time you load the example ou see skin colored but after reloads it's white